# Trouble linking libraries

Tags: react-native

I am trying to link this library called react-native-text-detector. 
However, I consistently get an error saying Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

I have tried changing the '\' in settings.gradle to '/'. However, the same error still pops up

All I have been doing is this

1. react-native init textDetectorTesting
2. npm install --save react-native-text-detector
3. react-native link

This is the error I received

```
BUILD FAILED in 41s
42 actionable tasks: 42 executed
Could not install the app on the device, read the error above for details.
Make sure you have an Android emulator running or a device connected and have
set up your Android development environment:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html

Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug

Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat installDebug
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:622:11)
    at Object.execFileSync (child_process.js:640:13)
    at runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\tanch\textdetector4\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:299:19)
    at buildAndRun (C:\Users\tanch\textdetector4\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:135:12)
    at isPackagerRunning.then.result (C:\Users\tanch\textdetector4\node_modules\react-native\local-cli\runAndroid\runAndroid.js:65:12)
    at process.internalTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:77:7)
```

Comment: try: `react-native link react-native-text-detector`

Comment: I just tried this, same error happened.